# Create schema in Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I need to create a custom mapping and also settings with synonym analyzer, so to have annotations on the document entity is not a solution.

Is there something build-in to create Elasticsearch schema on startup and do not create if it exists already?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IndexOperations` to write mappings and settings to an index - that's from version 4.0 on. In previous versions these methods were part of the `ElasticsearchOperations` interface.

You can check if the index exists, if not, create it and add these calls.